# Implementing remember-me in phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

At first I chose to use `put_session` to store user id because session hash cannot be tampered. However it seems like session cookie only persist during the browser session. When the user re-opens the browser, it's gone and the user has to log in again.

I read that another option might be to generate a secure random token for each user and store it in the database and put it in a regular cookie with high expiration date. However, given that this cookie doesn't have  tampering protection AFAIK (but I might be wrong) and connection is not always https, I guess anyone listening to http in the middle between the user and the server would be able to hijack the user session.

Hence the question is how can I persist user id in session in a secure way? Or what are the other ways?

Comment: I cannot give a detailed answer but I can give the proper directions. You can use `Phoenix.Token` (http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Token.html) to generate a token that you are going to store as a cookie using `put_resp_cookie` (http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#put_resp_cookie/4). Once there is a request and the user is not signed in, use `conn.cookies["remember_me"]` to see if a remember me cookie with the token is available and try to verify it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, seems like Phoenix.Token fits perfectly for this situation!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default cookie "max-age" is until close borwser.
You should give the cookie a really high "max_age" value:
http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#put_resp_cookie/4

---

Another way set "max_age", I can't find it in [official](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/sessions) doc，but it works:

```
defmodule HelloPhoenix.Endpoint do
  use Phoenix.Endpoint, otp_app: :hello_phoenix
. . .
  plug Plug.Session,
    store: :cookie,
    key: "_hello_phoenix_key",
    signing_salt: "Jk7pxAMf",
    max_age: 2592000 # 60*60*24*30
. . .
end
```

Comment: Here's a link to the official docs: https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#put_resp_cookie/4

Answer (score 2):

I'm implementing "Remember me" on my site. Using Phoenix.Token, the cookie can be read by clients. So I use MessageEncryptor (https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/master/lib/plug/crypto/message_encryptor.ex) to encrypt and sign the ticket. Then I use put_resp_cookie with a high max-age to put the encrypted ticket to cookie. Please note that IE doesn't support max-age so "Remember me" won't work on IE.