# How to make put_session last longer?

Tags: session, authentication, phoenix-framework

I'm trying my first toy app, and used the steps in "Programming Phoenix" to create an authentication. This is the method create in my session_controller (used to signin):

```
def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
  changeset = User.registration_changeset(%User{}, user_params)
  case Repo.insert(changeset) do
    {:ok, user} ->
      conn
      |> Myapp.Auth.login(user)
      |> put_flash(:info, "User created!")
      |> redirect(to: user_path(conn, :index))
  ...
end
```

And, my login method:

```
def login(conn, user) do
  conn
  |> assign(:current_user, user)
  |> put_session(:user_id, user.id)
  |> configure_session(renew: true)
end
```

Everything works fine, except that I need to login everytime that I close my browser. There's a way to extend the put_sesssion/assign? I searched for different authentication implementations, for questions, and in the Elixir/Phoenix documentation, but without success.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to is that the session cookie exists over closing the browser? In that case you can set the lifetime with max_age parameter in your engpoint.ex.

lib/Myapp/endpoint.ex:

```
plug Plug.Session,
  store: :cookie,
  key: "xxxxxx",
      .
      .
  max_age: 86400
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked exactly in the way that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any luck finding a way to extend session time. I can try to point you to a possible solution. Once the browser closes the sessions is over, but through "Phoenix.Token" and Cookies you should still be logged inn when you re-open the website. Check the answer to this question: [Implementing remember-me in phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578163/implementing-remember-me-in-phoenix)

Hopefully this is an alternative solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you, this approach looks like the same used in the "Programmnig Phoenix" book, I'll give it a try asap.